# How to change default fontFamily of app depending on OS(iOS or Android) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text

I want to create an app that feels native on both iOS and Android. On iOS, I want to use SF Pro text, and on Android different fontFamily. Does anyone have tried to do it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check current platform and assign font family based on it.

```dart
String? get appFontFamily {
  if (kIsWeb) {
    return null;
  }
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return ""; //provide proper name
  }
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    return ""; //provide proper name
  }
}
```

And place this getter on `MaterialApp`

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  fontFamily: appFontFamily,
  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
),
```